# What would be a suitable tag for the question "What is Islam's view on telepathy?" (8741)?

Tags: discussion, tag, tagging

The question [May a Muslim learn how to perform telepathy?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/8741) is currently tagged [untagged](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) and I was unable to come-up with a suitable tag for it. So what would be the suitable tags for this question, be it existing one and ones which have to be created?

I'm not in the favor of tagging it with [telepathy](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/telepathy) because that tag wouldn't be of much utility and wouldn't be able to gather more than 2-3 questions under it. But I could be wrong.

Suggestions?

Comment: [tag:supernatural]?

Comment: The word *supernatural* seems relative and time bound. You could turn it into an answer if your confident enough.

Answer (score 1):

> The question specifically is: is a Muslim allowed to learn about telepathy if at all there is any such thing like that?

Why not [hallal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hallal-haram)?

Comment: I find the [tag:halal-haram] tag being overused. At places where a more appropriate tag could be used.